# How to cancel long-running operations that require to start on the server side (rather than initiated by the client)

Tags: c#, events, asynchronous, cancellation

I have a class that exposes cancellable events according to the convention of raising an event before the state of the object changes and an event once the state is changed. The before-change event exposed by the publisher(server) is on  the form `StateChanging` and has as argument a [`CancelEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs%28VS.71%29.aspx), while the after-change event is on the form `StateChanged`. This provides the subscriber(client) of the event with the capability to cancel the operation before it starts.

Now I've changed one of these operations making it a long-running operation and I would like to give the subscriber the possibility to cancel the operation also after it has begun (and also to know the operation progress). I thought to the [event-based asynchronous pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx).

The problem is that I would like to keep the before-change and after-change event pattern since it's the publisher that at some point requires the operation, while in the asynchronous pattern it seems to me that it is the client that specifically ask a certain operation to be run asynhronously. Another possibility (but does not seem elegant to me) might be to have the server exposing an event (e.g. `OperationRequired`) that allow the client to know what needs to be accomplished on the server side and to call accordingly a `RunOperationAsync()` method. Please comment and add your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Event-based Asynchronous Pattern is generally preferred for operations that are controlled by a UI. The alternative, the Asynchronous Programming Model, is generally preferred for server or library APIs. If you've chosen to implement the EAP, that's fine.

Take a look at the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) implementation - it is the best example of the EAP that supports cancellation, among other things. It offers cancellation via the standard `CancelAsync()` method.

Comment: I know something about the BackgroundWorker, but I do not see the right way to use it in my case where I have the server that at a certain point starts an operation that was not specifically requested. I try to explain better: the client asks for a certain operation X and the server normally perform operation X; but sometimes the server (according to its state) requires to perform operation Y before X and, since Y can be long-running, the server should notify the client that it is starting Y and allow the client to eventually cancel it (which in turn will cancel also X).

Comment: If your client knows in advance whether it is prepared to wait for Y or not, it could set a property on your server object, say `bool CancelIfYRequired`, before it calls your `xxxAsync` method. Or it could pass it as an extra parameter. Similarly, you could add a property to your `xxxCompletedEventArgs` class to indicate when the operation was cancelled due to this condition. Your `CancelAsync` method should support cancellation while doing either Y or X.